# How do I make an inner loop in SAS?

Tags: loops, macros, sas

I am creating multiple datasets named "Taxes&i.(&i notes each new dataset according to the counter I. ) I then append all of the tables at the end with the table " want". When I finish going through the first macro loop i would like to go through another loop that changes the dates. So the line

*"DATE BETWEEN '14Feb2016:0:0:0'dt AND '16Feb2016:0:0:0'dt);*

would look like

*date between 'date1' and 'date2';*

I don't know how to create that loop though, so it goes back into the first loop. Then that loop finishes and it goes into the second loop changes the dates and back into the first loop finishes...into the second loop. 
Also there may be a way to make this less bulky and some how when the first loop is done executing maybe the dates can automatically increase by one day without them being declared. That will work also. I am just not sure which is best and possible.

```
%macro loop(list1, list2);

  %let n=%sysfunc(countw(&list1, %str('')));
  %do i=1 %to &n; 
    %let O_list1 = %scan(&list1, &i, %str('');
    %let O_list2 = %scan(&list2, &i, %str('');

/* another macro here called date_loop(date1, date2); */ 

proc sql; 
    create table taxes&i;
    select t1.tax_info
    FROM work.taxes&1 as t1
    WHERE (t1.O_LIST1 = &O_List2) AND
          (DATE BETWEEN '14Feb2016:0:0:0'dt AND '16Feb2016:0:0:0'dt);

%end;
%mend; 

run;

%list('1' '2', '3' '4') /*( this is "O_List1", "O_List2") */

data want;
   set abc.taxes: ;
run;
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Can you show what a few iterations of that may look like? Why create the multiple table's though, it doesn't seem to accomplish much here. Can you use BY group processing at all?

Comment: A good reference is a paper called 'Don't be Loopy' by David Cassell.

Comment: @Reeza in the real example code it's matching sensitive information codes that are different, so theres a pair let's say your full zipcode and your five digit zipcode are a pair. So 56789 and 123567894 are a pair. So that's why I don't group them. Is that a good reason or should I look more into grouping?

Comment: @Reeza I was not sure how to append each table per code pair with out creating new tables then appending them.

Comment: You should look more into grouping. I'm still not convinced you need this approach, though it probably works. You need to post more for us to understand the issue you're trying to solve though.